# Knights of Xentar final boss fight

Tags: knights-of-xentar

What is the most feasible way of defeating the final boss in Knights of Xentar? 
He is incredibly tough and even when I do some damage, he keeps healing himself at an incredible rate.

I've tried stacking on potions, throwing pretty much everything at him, weapons and spells alike, to no avail. Potions always run out and he's barely damaged because of the constant self-healing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly sounds terribly difficult - it seems like you're going to have to be particularly high level and have a TON of healing items if you hope to survive.  Most of the strategies I've found are more a "war of attrition" than anything else.

Although, here's a YouTube video of someone defeating him in about 45 seconds:

Comment: Thank you. The video is cut and edited though, so I'm not sure it only took that long. I've played it a while back, so I'm not sure, but I think that I had at least one potion type maxed to the cap.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have a lot of high potions. I recommend at least 50. Your level should also be over 55. Finally, set the cg level to the maximum (8). You should also try slowing down the game speed so you can heal your player more easily.

Comment: What is the 'cg level'?